# Using DVD drive from laptop as external disc bay

Tags: laptop

Is it possible to use the optical drive taken from a laptop as an external CD/DVD reader plugging by USB or another way of wiring? I have some drives like that and it would be nice to make from them something useful.

CD/DVD bays have SATA interface.

Answer (score 1):

You may find a laptop optical drive that has the SATA interface as its connection to the laptop. This means you can interface with a USB to SATA adapter or connect directly to the SATA interface.

If you do not have SATA connection on the optical drive, it would be necessary to locate the pinouts for the drive and determine the appropriate connections for your purposes. You'd also have to salvage the matching connector from the laptop or solder directly to the optical drive.

There's a substantial difference in difficulty between the two methods above. The first has a high possibility of success. The second has a high probability of failure.